# How credible is negative result of allergic skin tests?

Tags: allergy, sinus

Allergic tests performed a year ago confirmed I am not allergic to a cat. However, there a few signals that make me doubt in credibility of the test results:

- I felt much better (less sneezing, less pain in sinuses) when I left my apartment, where I keep my cat, for two weeks vacations by the sea.
- I also remember that a few days before allergic tests I had stopped taking calcium.
- I have also read and heard from a colleague who had two cats that you might be allergic to one cat but not to the other, so my guess is that test results might really depend what allergen is used.

Hence, my question how credible is negative result of allergic skin tests?

Would it make sense to repeat the tests again?